# Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script is working just fine but IE is giving me the error "Done but with errors on page" and I can't figure out why.

```
(function($){ 
     $.fn.extend({  
         tabify: function() {
            function getHref(el){
                hash = $(el).find('a').attr('href');
                if(hash)
                    return hash.substring(0,hash.length-4);
                else
                    return false;
                }
            function setActive(el){
                $(el).addClass('active');
                if(getHref(el))
                    $(getHref(el)).show();
                else
                    return false;
                $(el).siblings('li').each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                    $(getHref(this)).hide();
                });
            }
            return this.each(function() {
                var self = this;

                $(this).find('li>a').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href') + '-tab');
                });

                function handleHash(){
                    if(location.hash)
                        setActive($(self).find('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').parent());
                }
                if(location.hash)
                    handleHash();
                setInterval(handleHash,100);
                $(this).find('li').each(function(){
                    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
                        $(getHref(this)).show();
                    else
                        $(getHref(this)).hide();
                });
            }); 
        } 
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Click on it and figure out what the errors are?

Comment: Use the error console (or the yellow exclamation mark in IE) to find what errors *what* errors you actually get

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Or at least opening the Javascript error console to see what the "errors on page" are? (In Firefox, for example, this is Ctrl-Shift-J.)

Comment: have you tried clicking on it to see what the actual error was?

Comment: You could go to [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/) and paste the above code there to see what errors are thrown up (quite a few).

Answer (score 1):

Installing Firebug plugin on Firefox can help you to better understand what is not working well and many other things.

Comment: Should be a comment imo. And if it doesn't work in IE then Firebug might not help much...

Comment: I know, but unfortunately before this vote up I couldn't comment... a bit strange StackOverflow rule, isn't it?
Anyway Firebug can help showing if there's something not regular in the code, maybe even when Firefox processes it well.